# Editing a 9gb .sql file

Tags: sql-server, large-files, replace

I've got a "slightly" large sql script saved as a textfile. It totals in at 8.92gb, so it's a bit of a beast.

I've got to do some search and replaces in this file(specifically, change all NOT NULL to NULL, so all fields are nullable) and then execute the darned thing. Does anyone have any suggestions for a text editor that would be capable of this?

The other way that I can see to solve the problem is to write a program that reads a chunk, does a replace on the stuff I need, and then save it to a new file, but I'd rather use some standard way of doing this.

It also does not solve the problem of opening the beast up in sql server management studio to execute the darned thing...

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: You can use the SQL Server bcp command line utility to execute chunks of the file, there's no way you'll ever load the whole thing in SQL Manager. On my system bcp.exe is in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`sed`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) is built for exactly that kind of job.

```
sed -e 's/\( NOT\)\? NULL/ NOT NULL/g' < input.sql > output.sql
```

`sed` is also [available on Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm).

Edit: I modified my statement to avoid producing `NOT NOT NULL` when the input already contains `NOT NULL`.

Comment: Perfect(except for me wanting to change NOT NULL to NULL, not the other way around). Thank you!

Comment: Interestingly oracle export files are also a stream format (even though they're binary), so you can use sed to do search/replace operations on them.

Comment: @CEROQ: oops, my bad. But the other way around is even easier, so I'll keep it as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Use [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm), or simply `perl -pne 's/foo/bar/' file.sql > newfile.sql` (foo will be replaced with bar).

For loading SQL, use osql.exe that should be somewhere under c:\program files...\sql server\bin

Answer (score 0):

You can use an editor that maps files instead of loading them into memory. Like UltraEdit or Notepad++, I'm sure there are many more.

This is still slow but very functional.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using perl. It does an in-place text replacement. Use it as

```
perl -pie "s/ NOT NULL/ NULL/g" hugefile.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Careful with that axe Eugene...you don't want to clobber any WHERE clauses that should remain NOT NULL